# Retorno de função de leitura de arquivo em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Fiz esse trecho de código para ler através de um loop o conteúdo dos arquivos da lista.

```
lista_nome_base_docs = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
tamanho = len(lista_nome_base_docs)
print (tamanho)

lista_geral_arquivos = []


for i in range(tamanho):
     with open(lista_nome_base_docs[i],"r") as arquivo:
     conteudo = [line.strip() for line in arquivo if line.strip() != "" and line.strip() != "." and line.strip() != "\n" and line.strip() != "!" and line.strip() != "?" and line.strip() != ":" and line.strip() != "," and line.strip() != "ï»¿"]
     lista_geral_arquivos.append(conteudo)

print (lista_geral_arquivos)
```

porém miinha lista de listas fica com esse conteúdo:

```
[['€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.'], ['€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.'], ['€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.']]
```

alguém sabe como aparece as palavras ao invés desses caracteres estranhos? Já tentei o `.read()` e `.readlines()` e eles não estao colocando cada palavra numa posição da lista e sim esse monte de caracteres bagunçados...

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo desses arquivos?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss são somentes frases com **,** - **:** - **.** e **?** no meio das palavras, um texto bem simples mesmo

Comment: `for i in range(tamanho):
    with open(lista_nome_base_docs[i],"r") as arquivo:
        conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
        lista_geral_arquivos.append(conteudo)

print (lista_geral_arquivos)`  fazendo assim tbm lê um monte de coisa estranha @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui aqui.... depois que vc me perguntou sobre o conteúdo dos aqrquivos fui la conferir, e não sei por que motivos, a frase foi trocada por caracteres em japoneses hahaha, troquei o conteúdo e funcionou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal:

```
arquivos = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
lista_geral = []

for nome in arquivos:

    with open( nome, "r") as arq:

        a = []

        for linha in arq:
            a.append(linha.strip())

    lista_geral.append(a)

print( lista_geral )
```